# Induction problem: a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$ and prove that it holds for all $n \geq$ 1.

For this induction problem I chose $i = n +1$ so we have $(n+1)(n+1 +1) = (n+1)(n+2)$. Is that what we suppose to get for this problem?

Comment: If your summation is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(i+1)$, then your induction procedure is not correct. You haven't specified the result of the summation. Note that it breaks apart $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$. You want to use induction to prove that the summation equals this: $\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: See also: [Mathematical induction proof problem: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i(i+1) = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773586)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the binomial identity
$$
{2 \choose 2}  + {3 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 2} + \cdots + {k \choose 2}
= {k+1 \choose 3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^2+i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=$$ 
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{2n+4}{3}=$$
$$=\frac{2n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}=2\binom{n+2}{3}$$
hint for induction proof
$$2\binom{n+2}{3}+(n+1)(n+2)=\frac{2n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}+(n+1)(n+2)=$$
$$(n+1)(n+2)(n/3+1)=2\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{6}=2\binom{n+3}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and explain it by using another formula. Suppose we have $ \sum_{i=1}^n i $. I claim that this sum is equal to $n(n+1)/2$. How did I manage to come up with this ? Well, I just looked at the numbers and their sum and tried to find a pattern. Now to justify that this is indeed correct, I will use induction. So first you claim and then you prove. Try to come up with such a formula, break down the summation into two parts and then look for a pattern.

Comment: Others have already given the formula in their answers. Now you have to prove it. Induction is just a very quick and easy method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$1\times 2=\frac{1\times2\times3}{3},$$ and $$1\times 2 + 2\times 3 = \frac{2\times 3 \times 4}{3}.$$ And in general what you want to prove is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.$$