# Sum of $k(k-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

Probably very simple question, but I got stuck anyway.
Find $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k-1)$$
**Attempt**

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k-1) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k(k+1)}{2}=2(1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+...(1+2+...+n-1))$

Comment: Hint: $k(k-1) = k^2 - k$; and the finite sum you can split into two pieces.

Comment: A rather similar problem is to find the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers: [Simplify triangular sum of triangular numbers: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac12i(i+1))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1642906).

Comment: See also:
[For any integer $n\geq2$, prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1) = \frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176358),
[Induction problem: a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780162),
[Mathematical induction proof problem: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i(i+1) = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773586) or
[Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k(k+1)$ combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43317).

Comment: how do you use that sum symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n k
$$

Both are well [known results](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/power.htm)

$$
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2} - \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)} - \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)} = \frac{1}{3} n \left(n^2-1\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Use that:
$$k(k-1)=k^2-k$$
Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}$$
Then note that: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}=\frac n6(n+1)(2n+1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}=\frac n2(n+1)$$
And go from there

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One has
$$
k(k-1)=\frac{ k (k-1) (k+1)}{3}-\frac{(k-1) (k-2)k }{3} 
$$ giving a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general).

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your line of thought: note it is a sum of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k-1) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k(k+1)}{2}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(k+1)!}{2!(k-1)!}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {k+1\choose 2}=\\
2{(n-1+1)+1\choose 2+1}=2{n+1\choose 3}=2\cdot \frac{(n+1)!}{3!(n-2)!}=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you transition from the sum of combinations to one combination C(n+1, 3) ?

Comment: It is [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)