# Sum $\sum_{k=1}^n{k(k-1)}$

Tags: summation

I have a series as

$$n(n-1)+(n-1)(n-2)+(n-2)(n-3)+ \ldots +n\ \text{terms}$$

How to provide a summation of this series? I think it would be similar to:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N}(n-i)(n-(i+1)).$$

Comment: $3n(n+1) = n(n+1)(n+2)-(n-1)n(n+1)$ is also useful

Comment: See also:
[Sum of $k(k-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800485),
[For any integer $n\geq2$, prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1) = \frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176358),
[Induction problem: a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780162),
[Mathematical induction proof problem: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i(i+1) = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773586) or 
[Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k(k+1)$ combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43317).

Comment: You might want to check the advice given here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of $k(k-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800485/sum-of-kk-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{(k^2-k)}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Comment: Can you explain the first 2 iterations of $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)$. How did you reach to the summation? it would be nice if you could explain some steps

Comment: @christopher I added an additional step, hopefully that is clearer.

Comment: Remark:  this is also $2\times \binom {n}3$ which suggests a combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: @lulu Correction: $2\times{n+1\choose3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinatorial argument as lulu mentioned:

For each $n\geq 1$, define the set $S_n=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. For a fixed $n\geq 1$, let us count the number of ways to choose a subset $S_k\subseteq S_n$, with $k\leq n$, and then designate two special elements $a$ and $b\in S_k$ as "best" and "second best".

We can count this quantity in two ways:

1. For each $k\leq n$, we have the set $S_k=\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$. The number of ways to select the "best" element is $k$, and once that is chosen, the number of ways to select the "second best" element is $k-1$. Hence, there are $k(k-1)$ ways. Summing over each $k$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1)$.
2. Choose three distinct elements $a,b,c\in S_{n+1}$, and suppose without loss of generality $a<b<c$. There are ${n+1\choose 3}$ ways to do this. Let $k=c-1$, so that $k\leq n$. Then $a,b\in S_k$, so we may designate $a$ and $b$ to be "best" and "second best". There are two choices, either $a$ is "best" or $b$ is "best". Thus the number of ways is $2\times{n+1\choose 3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3}$.

Since we have counted the same quantity in two different ways, the results must be equal. Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1)=2{n+1\choose 3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3}$.

Comment: I think this is a much more enlightening way to understand the sum (+1).

Answer (score 1):

One can see this as follows: Since $k(k-1) = \dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1) -k(k-1)(k-2)}{3} = a_{k+1}-a_k$ where $a_k = \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3}$, one can see that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^n k(k-1) & = \sum_{k=1}^n ( a_{k+1}-a_k) \\ 
& = (a_{n+1} - a_n) + (a_{n} + a_{n-1}) + \cdots + (a_2 + a_1) \\ 
& = a_{n+1} - a_1 = (n+1)\cdot n \cdot (n-1)/3
\end{align*}

This method can induce the formulae for $f(a, n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)\cdots(k+a-1)$. ($a \in \mathbb{N})$.

My flavor is first have $f(a, n)$ and use this to know what is $\sum_{k=1}^n k^a$, not the other direction.