# How can simplify this summation notation

Tags: summation

So I have just started learning about summations, and I am stuck with this problem for a while, I need to simplify this summation to get a simpler expression, $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)$ where n is given.

Any help would be much appreciated and Thank you.

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i}i(i+1)=\sum_{i}i^{2}+\sum_{i}i$. Do you know the closed form for the two sums on the right hand side?

Comment: @parsiad Yes I do!!!, Thank you I got it now.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780162/induction-problem-a-formula-for-sum-i-1n-ii1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that often groups like $i(i+1)$ call for telescopic summation.

It is well known that $\dfrac 1{i(i+1)}=\dfrac 1i-\dfrac 1{i+1}$

Here it is slightly different, we have to increase the degree:

$U_{i}-U_{i-1}=i(i+1)(i+2)-(i-1)i(i+1)=3i^2+3i=3i(i+1)$

Therefore $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i(i+1)=\dfrac 13(U_n-U_0)=\dfrac 13n(n+1)(n+2)-0$

This works similarly for $\sum i(i+1)(i+2)$ if you want to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need an additional answer that don't require you to remember the formula of $\sum{n^2}$ and $\sum{n}$, I can give one for you:

Let $$A = \sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1) = 1.2 + 2.3 + ... + n(n+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow 3A=1.2.3 + 2.3.3 + 3.4.3 + ... + n(n+1).3$$
$$\Rightarrow 3A=1.2.3 + 2.3.(4-1) + 3.4.(5-2) ... + n(n+1)(n+2 - (n-1))$$
$$\Rightarrow 3A=1.2.3 + 2.3.4 - 1.2.3 + 3.4.5-2.3.4 ... + n(n+1)(n+2) - (n-1)n(n+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow 3A=n(n+1)(n+2)$$
$$\Rightarrow A = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$